# PHP json_decode returns null

Tags: php, json

I'm writing PHP code that uses a database. To do so, I use an array as a hash-map.
Every time content is added or removed from my DB, I save it to file.

I'm forced by my DB structure to use this method and can't use mysql or any other standard DB (School project, so structure stays as is).

I built two functions:

```
function saveDB($db){
    $json_db = json_encode($db);
    file_put_contents("wordsDB.json", $json_db);
} // saveDB

function loadDB(){
    $json_db = file_get_contents("wordsDB.json");
    return json_decode($json_db, true);
} // loadDB
```

When echo-ing the string I get after the encoding or after loading from file, I get a valid json (Tested it on a json viewer) Whenever I try to decode the string using `json_decode()`, I get null (Tested it with `var_dump()`).

The json string itself is very long (~200,000 characters, and that's just for testing).

I tried the following:

- Replacing single/double-quotes with double/single-quotes (Without any backslashes, with one backslash and three backslashes. And any combination I could think of with a different number of backslashes in the original and replaced string), both manually and using `str_replace()`.
- Adding quotes before and after the json string.
- Changing the page's encoding.
- Decoding without saving to file (Right after encoding).
- Checked for slashes and backslashes. None to be found.
- Tried `addslashes()`.
- Tried using various "Escape String" variants.

`json_last_error()` doesn't work. I get no error number (Get null, not 0).

It's not my server, so I'm not sure what PHP version is used, and I can't upgrade/downgrade/install anything.

I believe the size has something to do with it, because small strings seem to work fine.

Thanks Everybody :)

Comment: Zip your actual file, upload it somewhere for anyone else to test. Else this might become a guessing game. || Various failure causes include a UTF-8 BOM prefix, an alltogether invalid charset in strings, or simply an out-of-memory error - deeply nested PHP arrays are expensive, and `json_decode` itself hold some state data while processing. || Else try a different JSON library; PEARs Services_Json, or up_json_decode from upgradephp.

Comment: can you show the output of `JSON` (maybe on pastebin.com) which is not working with `json_decode` for testing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use other json libraries, since I have no control on the server and have no idea what's installed there.
The json can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0nm040wjfgzq25/wordsDB.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON file change null to "null" and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your file is UTF8 encoded. `json_decode` works with UTF8 encoded data only.

EDIT:
After I saw uploaded JSON data, I did some digging and found that there are 'null' key. Search for:

*"exceeding":{"S01E01.html":{"2217":1}},**null**:{"S01E01.html":*

Change that **null** to be valid property name and `json_decode` will do the job.

Comment: Had the same problem and it turned out to be an encoding issue too.

Comment: I get null even when I don't go through the file (Encode and decode right away), and decode works with small jsons, so I believe the file isn't the issue.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any way to check what is the recursion limit?

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy/paste. Should be _nesting limit_, which is 20(PHP 5.2.2) and 128(PHP 5.2.3+)

Comment: I spent three hours looking for this answer...thank you so much, Boris!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week. my json was valid according to jsonlint.com.

My json string contained a # and a & and those two made json_decode fail and return null.

by using var_dump(json_decode($myvar)) which stops right where it fails I managed to figure out where the problem was coming from.

I suggest var_dumping and using find dunction to look for these king of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the off chance.. and more for anyone hitting this thread rather than the OP's issue...I missed the following, someone had **htmlentities($json)** way above me in the call stack.  Just ensure you haven't been bitten by the same and check the html source.

Kickself #124